# Send message to group by group name

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I need to send message to Telegram group by group name. Problem, that i send messages by python bot. All is good, but it always send by bot name. I make bot admin in group.

I try settings in botfather

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to assign a name by editing the bot in telegram (you can message botfather `/help` to see available commands)

You have `/setname` command to change bots name

reference: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Tips-Tricks/Step-by-step-sending-a-notification-to-the-telegram-group-with/td-p/390324

Comment: I do not need change bot name, but thx